# TeXShop search not working for multiple file source

Tags: texshop, forward-inverse-search

I am using TeXShop 3.26 under Mavericks. I have SyncTeX selected as the sync method. Searching works both ways in general (source to pdf and pdf to source). However, when editing a multifile source where there is a "root" document with sections included with `\input{}`, and similarly subsections within those, forward search (source to PDF) doesn't work. Nothing happens. PDF to source still works fine.

Is this known/expected behaviour? Is there any setting I can make to fix it?

Answer (score 8):

In section 2.4 (*Working with a Large Document*) of the "TEXShop tips & tricks" there are some clues for you.

> It is often handy to break a large document into more manageable
>   subordinate parts and then create a “root” file which contains the
>   preamble and \include commands to bring all the parts together for
>   typesetting. To have TEXShop "know" which file to typeset when working
>   on a subordinate file put the line

```
% !TEX root = path/to/rootfile.tex
```

> at the top of your subordinate file; path/to/rootfile.tex is the
>   relative or absolute path to the root file for this document.

This is has two benefits:

1. If you <kbd>Command ⌘+T</kbd> in included file, Texshop will still typeset the correct root.
2. Sources and pdf are properly synchronized for searching

---

P.S. You can access to "TEXShop tips & tricks" from help menu.

Comment: Could someone test this and tell me, if it works? Thank you, Pouya, I'd like to give you that bounty but I can't proof your work.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, I will check it tonight and will update the answer accordingly. Give me couple of hours please...

Comment: @LaRiFaRi,  tested it on Texshop 3.18, OS X Mavericks. It works fine.