# Search multiple files in TeXShop

Tags: texshop

I prefer to split up bigger projects into multiple files, where I use the following "magic comment" to point to the root file:

```
% !TEX root = ../my-root.tex
```

Sometimes, I have to search globally for a certain string, hence, in multiple files within the current project. [Atom](https://atom.io/) has this neat "Find in Project" feature you can use with `cmd + shift + f` respectively `ctrl + shift + f`.

Does TeXShop has something comparable? The standard search dialog only includes the current file.

**EDIT:** I just found out that this has been on the [mailing list](http://tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2011-December/047930.html) at least since 2011. But as far as I can see there is no official issue tracker, where one can check the status of feature requests like this.

Comment: This answer doesn't work? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155150/texshop-search-not-working-for-multiple-file-source I suppose from the answer that the normall search behavior will work for all files. But I am not sure about that.

Comment: @koleygr Unfortunately no, also the question title is a bit confusing. It's about syncing sources to PDF and vice versa if I get it right.

Comment: Unfortunately no, TeXShop doesn't have this functionality.

Comment: @AlanMunn Too bad, but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately TeXShop does not have this functionality (as of v3.88). When I need to do this sort of thing, I use another editor (in my case TextWrangler/BBEdit) but as you note, Atom can also do this, as can other editors, I'm sure.

Comment: TeXShop doesn't really have a concept of a `project` so can't do multi-file searches. I wonder if someone can write an applescript (TeXShop Macro) to deal with projects.

Comment: @HerbSchulz The concept of project isn't really necessary for multifile search. TextWrangler has multifile search and replace without projects.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I agree with Alan Munn as I also think that the project concept isn't necessary. Moreover, `% !TEX root` is already used by TeXShop and could be helpful when implementing such a feature since it gives insights into the project structure.

Comment: @beatngu13 : But the root file doesn’t contain that line. The only way to do it right is to recursively look for `\input` and `\include` commands. Even that could lead to problems. PS: how do you tell BBEdit/TextWrangler what files to search?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Indeed, but as you said, checking `input`/`include` can be used as well. There're plenty of ways to do that, it's a solved problem in other editors. I hope the folks at TeXShop someday come up with a nice solution.

Comment: @HerbSchulz In TextWrangler/BBEdit you can choose files in any number of ways: open documents, open windows,  selected files in a particular folder, recursively through a folder etc.

Comment: While TeXShop can't do multi-file searches recent versions (latest is 3.88) under macOS Sierra or later can create a tabbed window with all the related files (up to 20) so it can be easy to switch between relevant documents and search. Not the same thing, but...